# Why does AlertDialog.dialog.show() crash the second time through?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, showdialog

My Android app displays an AlertDialog and everything is fine the first time through. However, after displaying and then cancelling the Dialog, it crashes on show() the second time. I tried the suggestions made in similar posts but nothing helped. Here's my code:

```
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.config_add: 
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.create_content_server_config_title);
        builder.setView(config_view);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_confirm_create_config_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked Create button
                Toast.makeText(ManageContentServers.this, config_name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_config_cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're using "setView". You're need to recreate the dialog everytime!

```
 private void showDialog() { 
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); builder.setTitle(R.string.create_content_server_config_title); builder.setView(config_view);  builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_confirm_create_config_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked Create button
                        Toast.makeText(ManageContentServers.this, config_name.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_config_cancel_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    });
                    dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show(); 
        }


    case R.id.config_add:
    showDialog();
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're saying the same thing, but I fixed the problem more easily by moving

```
config_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecs_config_fields, null);
```

from the onCreate() method to onClick(), just before builder.setView(config_view);